# Installing Thinking Sphinx on Openshift - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, openshift

Openshift by Redhat seems to be a cool PaaS alternative to Heroku, but does anyone know if it is possible to install sphinx on Openshift so it can be used in a rails app with Thinking Sphinx? Any commments would be appreciated!

Comment: Check this link https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/do-it-yourself                                                               In the link see this text, OpenShift can run any binary that will run on RHEL 6.2 x64 because the OpenShift execution environment is a carefully secured Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2 running on x64 systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this is going to help or not.But on open-shift you can compile any source and install it to any prefix.Like $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR.
I think the best way to do this,Creating a DIY(Do it yourself) app and compile everything from sources, or creating a ruby app and install the gems you want,modify the environment as you want.
This article may give you a idea about installing application from sources on open-shift. https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/enabling-python-27-on-a-paas-with-the-openshift-diy-app-type